# Powershell : Remote Internet Connection check

Tags: powershell, com, activator, createinstance

Is there any way to check, if remote computer has internet connection.

I want to check internet connection status before calling COM on remote server.

```
"[activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session","$comp"))"
```

Thx

Answer (score 3):

One idea that comes in mind is to issue a ping command (from your machine) where the source of the ping is the remote computer and the target could be any valid Internet (ip) address (source http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/08/26/pstip-a-hidden-gem-of-the-test-connection-cmdlet/):

```
[bool](Test-Connection -Source RemoteComputer -ComputerName google.com -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```